# Error occurred during initialization of VM. Corrupted ZIP library: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8, macos-catalina

I'm consistently getting the error executing keytool, java, javac, etc:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Corrupted ZIP library: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libzip.dylib
```

I've tried to reinstalling my JRE and JDK. The same problem persists for both versions of JDK, jdk1.8.0_231 and jdk13.0.1.

I tried using the Java binary from the Android Studio installation as well but it gives the same error. The binary I used: "/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool"

I'm currently running Java 8 Update 231 on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I also struggled with this and just got to the bottom of it.

First, I noticed that I was able to run java as superuser, so stuff like this worked fine:

```
sudo java ...
sudo javac ...
```

However, this was annoying and a bit weird, so I went digging and found that I had `$JAVA_HOME` in my `$PATH` in `~/.zshrc` (yours may be `~/.bashrc` or whatever shell you're using), like:

```
export $JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk_whatever/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I removed that second line, and used the java located in `/usr/bin` as is default and already in my path, and this worked. I could still switch my java version with `$JAVA_HOME` and it functioned correctly.

Still, I couldn't run java with `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`, and some stuff was still broken – in my case the maven/run configuration UI tools in IntelliJ.

Finally, I noticed that there was yet another problematic line in my `.zshrc`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
```

I'm not entirely sure why I added that, but I removed it, refreshed my terminal, and suddenly everything was OK again.

It may be fine to just prepend/append values to this environment variable, but I haven't needed to do that yet.